# contracts.OutofGas when i want to uplooad smart contract

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, substrate-contracts-node

i want upload smart contract in the https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/contracts but it when i press the depoloy button , it show me this error :

[image]

`polkadot-v0.9.34`

`substrate-contracts-node : substrate-contracts-node 0.23.0-87a3d76c880`

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?**

Comment: Where are you deploying the Smart Contract (chain)? Do you have  enough Balance in the account you are using?

Comment: Can you try in: https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/
polkadot js UI is not updated to WeightV2 ( > polkadot v0.9.33)

Comment: @AlexBean i created solochain with substrate also  i want upload this in polkadot.js local test .

Comment: @P.Ossun I tried to use contract-ui in it works , but i want to know hiw can i solve this problem .

Comment: @MrCoder Having polkadot js apps team fixing the issue: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/8538 =)

Comment: @P.Ossun which way is better for production ? Contract-ui or polkadot.js ?

Comment: @MrCoder Contracts UI, it's better maintained for contracts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the `polkadot-js` UI unfortunately doesn't support Weights V2 yet.

You are better off using https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/ for now.